# Having test coverage problems with Rails instance method in model with Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, rails-models, stripe-payments

I'm using the Simplecov gem to output my test coverage and for an odd reason can not get 2 lines in my Rails instance method in my model to be captured. Also, any insight into why Simplecov states that the entire method is covered except for the 2 lines when I have not even included a describe block within my specs would be great as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def process
  if valid?
    payment = Stripe::Charge.create(amount: amount, currency: "usd",
                                    card: stripe_card, capture: false)

    if (payment[:card][:address_line1_check] &&
        payment[:card][:cvc_check] &&
        payment[:card][:address_zip_check]).eql?("pass")
      charge = Stripe::Charge.retrieve(payment[:id]) # This line is not captured
      charge.capture # This line is not captured
    end

    self.transaction_number = payment.id
    save!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplecov is showing you two things:

1. *At least once* during the test run, `process` is called.
2. *At no point* during the test run does the condition of the `if` statement evaluate to a truthy value; consequently, the body of the statement is never reached.

Simplecov doesn't care whether you explicitly created a `describe` block: Simplecov simply looks at which statements were executed during the test run.

Separately, I don't think the logic of your `if` condition does what you expect (and using `eql?` is not very idiomatic).

```
if (payment[:card][:address_line1_check] &&
    payment[:card][:cvc_check] &&
    payment[:card][:address_zip_check]).eql?("pass")
```

Each of these values can be one of {`nil`, `"pass"`, `"fail"`, `"unchecked"`}. A string value is truthy: `"a" && "b" == "b"` but `nil && "b" == nil`. Your code could be executed even if `address_line1_check` were `"fail"`.

If you want to test that *all three* values are equal to `"pass"`, this will do it:

```
if [payment[:card][:address_line1_check],
    payment[:card][:cvc_check],
    payment[:card][:address_zip_check]].all? { |v| v == "pass" }
```

Comment: Thanks so much threedaymonk. Great explanation and pointed me in the correct direction.